# Battlefield 3 logo effect

Tags: jquery, css, image

For those that have Battlefield 3, could someone please explain to me how to recreate the effect that makes the logo 'shimmer'. I know the image has 3 states (mouse-out, hover and mouse-in) but I have no idea how to make it shimmer.

The effect of the logo can be seen by logging into BF3 battlelog and mousing over the logo.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What jQuery libraries are loaded on the page? Use FireBug to have a look (net tab) and it should provide a hint.

Comment: Using Chrome's Inspect Element (scripts tab) it seems like it all is self made libraries.

Comment: It's a mouseenter event and a sprite - http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/public/base/bf3/header-logo2.png?v=590  Just do some googling on sprites and jquery mouseenter and you can easily do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the event that is attached to the image:

```
var $headerLogoBF3=$("a.base-header-logo-bf3");
$headerLogoBF3.pageBind("mouseover", function() {
  try {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"0px -136px"},80, function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"0px -68px"});
    });
  } catch(e){}
});
$headerLogoBF3.pageBind("mouseout",function( {
  try{
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"0px 0px"},"slow");
  } catch(e){}
});
```

Comment: Awesome! How did I not see that? Thanks a million Sani!

Answer (score 1):

No magic here, it just switches image when you hover. If you check the DOM when hovering the logo you'll see how the background-position jumps from 0 0 to 0 ~-100px and finally to 0 ~-50px, which, with this image http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/public/base/bf3/header-logo2.png?v=590, makes it first jump to the last "shimmery" one, then to the middle one.

Edit: To achieve this, what you'd do is say something like:

```
$('#logo').hover(function () {
    var logo = $(this);

    logo.css('background-position', '0 -100px');

    setTimeout(function () {
        logo.css('background-position', '0 -50px');
    }, 5);
}, function () {
    $(this).css('background-position', '0 0');
});
```

Edit2: You may not even need the setTimeout.

Comment: I noticed that. I just want to know what they use to create that pause.

Answer (score 0):

You actually answered your own question:

The image has a mouse-out, hover and mouse-in image. The hover is probably a small gif that gets replaced with the mouse-in image as soon as it's over. Nothing difficult and probably possible with pure css!

Good luck.

Edit: My answer was wrong. They are using one image over which they navigate depending on the mouse movement. See Powerbuoy's answer for the correct explanation.

Comment: But on mouse over, there is no pause, so you won't see the effect (as the change will be too fast). Am I right or am I missing something?  What I'm thinking is using a setTimeout function in javascript, with a 100ms interval. Do you think that'll work?

Comment: I was indeed wrong. Apparently they work with one image, where they view different parts of. Powerbuoy has the image in his post.

Comment: I also posted that I have the image in my initial post. EDIT : Well, rereading it I see that I say it has 3 images. Never mentioned that I had it. My bad!